# Laravel 5.8 background job is not in the background

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, queue

I have a library, which imports lots of images and I am trying to use Laravel background jobs. For queued jobs, I am following Laravel documentation.

First (create table):

```
php artisan queue:table
php artisan migrate
```

Then configuration in .env file for Redis:

```
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=43216
```

Create a job:

```
php artisan make:job CarsJob
```

CarsJob:

```php
public function handle() 
{
    $cars = new CarsLibrary();
    $CarsLibrary->importAll();
}
```

Dispatching a job in a some action in the controller:

First what I have tried:

```php
$importCarsJob = (new ImportCarsJob())->onQueue('import_cars');
$this->dispatch($importCarsJob );
```

Second what I have tried:

```php
$importCarsJob = new importCarsJob();
$this->dispatch($importCarsJob);
```

I have enabled Redis in my hosting. It is shared hosting.

If I access the URL, I see that this job is not in the background, because it needs more than a minute to finish the request.

EDIT:
The `env` file is above, this is `config/queue.php`:

```
    'connections' => [

    'sync' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
    ],
    ... other drivers like beanstalkd

    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 90,
    ],


    'redis' => [
        'driver' => 'redis',
        'connection' => 'default',
        'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
        'retry_after' => 90,
        'block_for' => null,
    ],

],
```

- I have no `REDIS_QUEUE` in `env` file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have not updated your queue connection in `config/queue.php` from `sync` to `redis` (or the environment variable `QUEUE_CONNECTION`). The `sync` driver will execute jobs immediately without pushing them on a queue.

By the way, you don't need the queue database table if you use the redis queue driver.

Comment: Thanks, there is a progress, now I am getting, `undefined index queue` warning in `RedisConnector` , `connectt`

Comment: Are you sure that your settings in `.env` and `config/queue.php` are correct? Maybe add the full content of both files to your question (not passwords/secrets or the `APP_KEY` of `.env` though!).

Comment: You are not supposed to change the `driver` of the `sync` connection! You should change the `queue.default` option from `sync` to `redis` (or instead you can also use `QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis` in your `.env` file). The config is a bit confusing there, but you don't need to change the connections, only the selected connection.

Comment: It seems that is in the background, now, but actually, it doesn't import nothing. It doesn't execute the code.

Comment: Whenever you update your code, you need to restart the queue worker(s). Use logging to see what happens in the queue.

Comment: Still nothing happen.

Comment: Well, it's hard to help you without further infos. But as this seems to be a whole other topic, I suggest opening a new question with as much details as you can provide.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will mark your answer, because it fixed the first problem.